# Developing SharePoint web part on one SharePoint but will be deployed on a completely different one

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

OK, so, here's the deal: The company I work for has a contract to develop a custom SharePoint web part for another company.  The other company is not open to allowing me to access their SharePoint so I am developing the web part against a SharePoint my company owns, and we will somehow (at this point I don't know quite how) get it from ours to theirs when development is complete.  Or at least that's the plan...

I was linking a JavaScript file on the .ascx for the web part (by dragging the js file into the markup view of the .ascx) and noticed the URL it generated: "/_layouts/15/MyWebPart/js/...".  Immediately this set off a red flag: What is that 15?  Where does it come from? *Is it going to be different on a different SharePoint?*

Is there any programmatic way to get that url?  Or even just the 15? If not, how will we handle deploying this on the target server?

Answer (score 1):

The "15" is the location for that version (2013 at least. Possibly 2016 too) of SharePoint binaries, configuration files and other SharePoint server files (Long story on why it's now 15 without having 15 versions). It is sometimes called the "15 hive" or "14 hive" (for SharePoint 2010).

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/427416/What-is-SharePoint-2010-14-hive-directory